# Import big text images in shiny App with R

Tags: r, image, shiny, rstudio, shinyapps

In my project I developed algorithms with R and R studio to process big images from microscopy analysis. I work on big matrix of pixel value (around 3Gb ), extract biological informations from specific regions of these images especially perform particle detection at specific position of the matrix and then perform statistical analysis.

To be able to transfer the whole process to other people without applying multiple scripts functions... I tried to create a Shiny App but I struggle to import the big images .txt

Actually I use as.matrix(read.table()) function on the file provided by the shiny app user through the file input box
Is any one has an idea to import these matrix easily and more quickly ? even  on Rstudio I wait ~20minutes for each picture import.

Thanks a lot in advance for the answers,

Best,

Romain

Comment: This question has been answered in this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quickly reading very large tables as dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try solutions advised in this topic, and I'll try to apply them in my shiny project